# TimePicker using Mobile Angular UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

UI Bootstrap (Angular Ui Team) has a nice looking TimePicker but I coundn't find similar in Mobile Angular UI. Am I missing something here? or any workaround?

**Update:**
What I'm asking here is that why TimePicker  is not available (or Did I miss it? if I did, show me some code sample or link to a documentation) and Why Only the DatePicker is available in both platforms. I guess they are somehow derived from the same source (Bootstrap). Down voting is a good thing If I have asked something I shouldn't or simply a silly Question. What ever the reason for down voting I appreciate your comments about that. It helps me to improve my self. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. :)

Nothing stops you mixing Mobile Angular UI & UI Bootstrap.